# Matplotlib 軸と目盛りの距離の変更

Tags: python, matplotlib

お世話になります．

以下のような図を，matplotlibで作成しました．
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

グラフの右下・左下で，x軸・y軸の軸目盛りが近づいてしまい，見づらくなってしまっています．

そこで，ｘ軸の軸目盛りをｘ軸から離したいのですが，方法が分かりません．
ご教授お願いします．

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Axes.tick_params()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params) で `pad` を設定すると良いです。

```
ax.tick_params(pad=〈tick と tick label の間の距離を float で指定する〉)
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます．見やすい図を作成することができました．